# Create Angular Modal Outside of Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In `app.js`, and specifically within `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart')` I have a function that creates a modal:

```
setIdleTimeout.$inject = ['$uibModal']
function setIdleTimeout(timerStart, timerDuration, $scope, $uibModal){
    console.log('timerStart: ', timerStart, 'timerDuration: ', timerDuration)

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('setTimeout running')
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: '****',
            controller: '****',
            scope: $scope,
            size: size,
            backdrop  : 'static',
            resolve: {}
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem
        }, function () { })

    }, 10000)
}
```

Im getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`, even tho Im injecting it and including the source code in `Index.html`

`<script src="~/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>`

How do I create a modal outside of a controller?

Answer (score 1):

Might need more detail about your code structure, specially the context where you call $rootScope.$on()...

I think the problem you have here is `$uibModal` is not properly injected. Instead of using `$inject` in the `setIdleTimeout` function, tried to inject the `$uibModal` in the the same level as where you inject your `$rootScope`.